# UITableViewCell change label constraints when increasing font size

Tags: swift, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint

I want to change label top and bottom constraint in cell when increasing font size:

```
   @IBAction func changeFontSize(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        fontSize += 2
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        self.tableView.reloadInputViews()
        self.tableView.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()

    }
```

And in cell:

```
cellLabel.numberOfLines = 0
cellLabel.sizeToFit()


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! TableCells

    let cellTitle = dataArray.object(at: indexPath.row) as! NSString
    cell.cellLabel.attributedText = self.convertStringToAttributeText(text: cellTitle)


    let paragraphSpace = fontSize / 3
    cell.cellLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let hConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-20-[label]-20-|", options: .init(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: ["label": cell.cellLabel])
    cell.contentView.addConstraints(hConstraints)

    let vConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-\(paragraphSpace)-[label]-\(paragraphSpace)-|", options: .init(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: ["label": cell.cellLabel])
    cell.contentView.addConstraints(vConstraints)



    return cell

}
```

Auto cell height is working good, but the CONSTRAINTS does not change!

Comment: I see two possibility, you might have not removed existing constraints from your labels causing conflicting constraints and iOS chose the existing ones to follow therefore no change in constraints. Otherwise it maybe that UITableViewAutomaticDimension gives slightly less vertical space than required depending on the font size such that the extra space supposed to be created by your constraints is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622513-addconstraints):

> When developing for iOS 8.0 or later, use the NSLayoutConstraint class’s activate(*:) method instead of calling the addConstraints(*:) method directly. The activate(_:) method automatically adds the constraints to the correct views.

Also, I would recommend to override `updateConstraints()` in your cell`s subclass instead of deleting and recreating the constraints every time the cell gets used.